# jQuery load content when scroll down

Tags: jquery

I am looking for a solution:

What if there is a list of products, 1000's of products, and I want to load them all in one single page.

What can I use in order to load this list when I scroll down **ONLY**, row by row? So that page will not load too much at the beginning?

I had a look over the **Jquery Lazy plugins,** but they do load the full list anyway at the beginning.

Comment: You are looking for a jQuery infinite scroll plugin: https://www.google.com/search?q=jQuery+infinite+scroll+plugin Here is a good demo of 5 of the best: http://www.jquery4u.com/tutorials/jquery-infinite-scrolling-demos/

Comment: Your examples looks like what I need!!! I must try them! thanks!